# Perfect forwarding for functions inside of a templated C++ class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

Is there a good way to get perfect forwarding for functions inside of a templated class?  Specifically, in the code

```c++
#include <iostream>

// Forward declare a Bar
struct Bar;

// Two different functions that vary based on the kind of argument
void printme(Bar const & bar) {
    std::cout << "printme: constant reference bar" << std::endl;
}
void printme(Bar && bar) {
    std::cout << "printme: r-value reference bar" << std::endl;
}

void printme2(Bar const & bar) {
    std::cout << "printme2: constant reference bar" << std::endl;
}
void printme2(Bar && bar) {
    std::cout << "printme2: r-value reference bar" << std::endl;
}

// Some class with a bunch of functions and possible some data (though, not
// in this one)
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    void baz(T && t) {
        printme(std::forward <T> (t)); 
    }
    void buz(T && t) {
        printme2(std::forward <T> (t)); 
    }
};

struct Bar {};

int main() {
    Foo <Bar> foo;        
    foo.baz(Bar());

    // Causes an error
    Bar bar;
    //foo.buz(bar);
}
```

Uncommenting the last bit of code, we get the error:

```
    test03.cpp: In function 'int main()':
    test03.cpp:51:16: error: cannot bind 'Bar' lvalue to 'Bar&&'
         foo.buz(bar);
                    ^
    test03.cpp:30:10: note: initializing argument 1 of 'void Foo<T>::buz(T&&) [with T = Bar]'
         void buz(T && t) {
              ^
    Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Now, we can fix this problem by moving the template argument inside of the class:

```c++
#include <iostream>

// Forward declare a Bar
struct Bar;

// Two different functions that vary based on the kind of argument
void printme(Bar const & bar) {
    std::cout << "printme: constant reference bar" << std::endl;
}
void printme(Bar && bar) {
    std::cout << "printme: r-value reference bar" << std::endl;
}

void printme2(Bar const & bar) {
    std::cout << "printme2: constant reference bar" << std::endl;
}
void printme2(Bar && bar) {
    std::cout << "printme2: r-value reference bar" << std::endl;
}

// Some class with a bunch of functions and possible some data (though, not
// in this one)
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    void baz(T && t) {
        printme(std::forward <T> (t)); 
    }
    template <typename T_>
    void buz(T_ && t) {
        printme2(std::forward <T_> (t)); 
    }
};

struct Bar {
    Bar() {} 
};

int main() {
    Foo <Bar> foo;        
    foo.baz(Bar());

    Bar bar;
    foo.buz(bar);
}
```

However, this seems like it'll be really verbose.  For example, imagine that we have a large number of functions that all depended on the type `T` and needed perfect forwarding.  We'll need separate template declarations for each.  Also, the class `Foo` may contain a data of type `T` and we want functions that are consistent with this data.  Certainly, the typechecker will catch mismatches, but this system isn't as straightforward as just having a single template argument, `T`.

Basically, what I'm wondering is if there's a better way to do this or are we stuck just templating each function in the class separately?

Comment: I like to write short wrappers like `void foo(T const& x)`, and `void foo(T&& x)` that both call (with `std::move` in the latter case) a private inner method that uses perfect forwarding (`template<typename U> void foo(U&& x)`) and does the real work. That way, your public API is explicit and catches errors early, yet there's almost no duplication in the private innards.

Comment: For a function that merely observes the value of its arguments (and doesn't modify them nor gets more efficient by potentially stealing their resources), a `const&` parameter and no perfect forwarding is still a viable and often the best solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The templates are *very* different.

In the first code, your template parameter is `Bar`, and so I'm not sure even what it's doing, because you should NOT be using `std::forward` except with reference-qualified-types.  I *think* it's `void buz(Bar&& t) {printme((Bar)t);}`, and the compiler is balking at passing the lvalue `bar` in `main` to a function expecting `Bar&&`.

In the second codeblock, the template parameter is `Bar&` due to the universal reference, so the code is `void buz(Bar& t) {printme((Bar&)t);}`, which binds to to the lvalue `bar` in `main` just fine.

If you want perfect forwarding, the template parameter must be the rvalue-qualified type you want passed on, which means you *almost always* have to have the function itself be templated.  However, do yourself a favor and name it different.  The `T` and the `T_` will be *different types*.

```
template <typename U>
void buz(U&& t) {
    printme2(std::forward<U>(t)); 
}
```

If you want SFINAE, you can add that too:

```
template <typename U,
    typename allowed=typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<Bar,U>::value,void*>::type
    >
void buz(U && t) {
    printme2(std::forward <U> (t)); 
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, `forward` can also be useful for template parameters of class templates. Consider `template<typename T> struct wrapper { T t; operator T() && { return forward<T>(t); } }; wrapper<vector<int>> w{{1000, 42}}; vector<int> v; wrapper<vector<int>&> x{v};`

Comment: Should one not `SFINAE` test `U` to make sure it is appropriate?

Comment: @Yakk: I tend to shy away from `SFINAE` unless it's required to get overloading to work right, and prefer `static_assert`.  However, I figured `static_assert` doesn't give much benefit over the normal error message here, so I let it be.

Comment: @MooingDuck Good plan.  But that does move your errors to "late" errors, which prevents other code from testing if a given call is a valid one "early" in their own SFINAE.  I cannot wait for concepts, which will make moving the errors early so much less painful.