# std::forward not allowing lvalues to be accepted

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

Below is an implementation of the `insert()` member function of a max heap. I tried to use `std::forward` as I think it can be alternative to writing an overload of this function that accepts lvalues. However, the code is still not working for lvalues. Any ideas why?

Note: `values` is a private `vector<T>` in the `max_heap` class.

```cpp
template <typename T, typename compare_type>
void max_heap<T, compare_type>::insert(T&& item){
    if(values.empty()){
        values.push_back(std::forward<T>(item));
        return;
    }
        
    values.push_back(std::forward<T>(item));
        
    size_t child_pos = values.size()-1;
    size_t parent_pos = (child_pos-1)/2;
        
    //stop swapping either when inserted child at root or smaller than parent
    while(child_pos != 0 && pred(values[parent_pos], values[child_pos])){
        std::swap(values[parent_pos], values[child_pos]);
        child_pos = parent_pos;
        parent_pos = (child_pos-1)/2;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't actually have any perfect forwarding here. `T&&` is not a universal reference because `T` is bound to your `max_heap` instead of being deduced from arguments on call site, hence `T&&` is a simple rvalue reference. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638627/perfect-forwarding-for-functions-inside-of-a-templated-c-class).

Comment: Sorry I don't understand it quite well yet, how can I fix this problem? the link sent suggest ```template <typename U>
void buz(U&& t) {
    printme2(std::forward<U>(t)); 
}``` which seems like what I did already

Comment: Do you see the difference between `template<class T> class foo { void bar(T&&); };` and `class foo { template<class T> void bar(T&&); };`?

Comment: thanks, I understand the concept now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a forwarding reference, your argument's type must exist as a template parameter of the same function template. (See *(1)* of [forward references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) for more information.)

In your case, the template parameter `T` is from the class `max_heap` and not from the function's template argument list, so `item` serves as an rvalue reference (which can't bind to lvalues) and not as a forwarding reference.

For your case, try something like this:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
// Other header includes go here ...

template <typename T, typename compare_type>
class max_heap {
    // Other instance variables go here ...
public:
    template <typename U> // <- Notice how the template parameter 'U' is bound to the 'same function template'
    void insert(U&& item);
    // Other member methods go here ...
};

// ...

template <typename T, typename compare_type>
template <typename U>
void max_heap<T, compare_type>::insert(U&& item){
    if(values.empty()){
        values.push_back(std::forward<U>(item));
        return;
    }
    
    values.push_back(std::forward<U>(item));
    
    size_t child_pos = values.size()-1;
    size_t parent_pos = (child_pos-1)/2;
    
    //stop swapping either when inserted child at root or smaller than parent
    while(child_pos != 0 && pred(values[parent_pos], values[child_pos])){
        std::swap(values[parent_pos], values[child_pos]);
        child_pos = parent_pos;
        parent_pos = (child_pos-1)/2;
    }
}

// Other definitions go here ...
```

Comment: What if I used <T> as the forwarded type instead of U? Both seems to work, but is there any difference in using one as opposed to the other)

Comment: @LHC2012 Yes, both are different. `U` is deduced from the function's parameter while `T` exists inside the class `max_heap<T, compare_type>`. If you see the implementation of [`std::forward()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward), you would see that it returns a `T&&` but if you do `std::forward<T>(item)` it will give an rvalue reference but in case of `std::forward<U>(arg)` it will give you the actual reference after perfect forwarding. See [this small example to see it in action](https://godbolt.org/z/KfeKb7r67).